# Where can I write code to add parallax in my Opencart site?

Tags: opencart, parallax

I want to add `parallax code` to a newsletter in my **opencart** code and I can't find the file where I can write the code.
Anyone who can help?
I tried all the files but I couldn't find anything!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the newsletter file in the **/catalog/view/theme/default/template/account** folder.